# How can I use Scanner to update a date field in my java code

Tags: java, jdbc, java.util.scanner

Ive tried using:

```
keyboard.nextLine(),
```

which gives an error saying that a string cannot be converted to a date, then I tried using:

```
keyboard.nextDate();
```

Which gives the error "Cannot find symbol"

```
 System.out.print("Enter a Release date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
        e.setReleaseDate(keyboard.next());
        keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: Have you declared and assigned `keyboard` anywhere?  E.g. `final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`?

Comment: What about `e`?

Comment: Your format pattern for the date input (though it is just a hint) is wrong, you are currently asking for year-minutes-day (`"yyyy-mm-dd"`) but you should ask for year-month-day (`"yyyy-MM-dd"`).

Answer (score 1):

The method setReleaseDate probably expects a date, but the method next returns a String. You need to parse that String with a SimpleDateFormat, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateMethod(format.parse(scanner.next()));
}

public static void dateMethod(Date date) {
    System.out.println(date);
}
```